# Why an anonymous thread finished faster in SpringBootTest than normal unit test?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm trying to do some simple java multithread test. And the same function behaved differently depending on if I use SpringBootTest or not. The code is as below:

Target class:

```
public class Foo {
    private int i = 0;

    public void setI() {
        new Thread(() -> i = 1).start();
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

The REST interface of Foo:

```
@RestController
    public class FooController {

    private static Foo foo = new Foo();

    @RequestMapping(path = "getFoo")
    public int getFoo() {
        return foo.getI();
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "setFoo")
    public void setFoo() {
        foo.setI();
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class FooControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void noRest() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setI();
        assertThat(foo.getI(), is(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void rest() {
        template.postForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/setFoo", null, Integer.class);
        ResponseEntity<Integer> response = template.postForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/getFoo", null, Integer.class);
        assertThat(response.getBody(), is(1));
    }
}
```

The purpose in class Foo is to start a new thread to set the value of i.

Since creating a thread will cost some time, the main thread in test case noTest() always finish earlier before the anonymous thread which is created in setI(). Hence the value of i is unchanged.

The strange thing is, if I add trigger the REST interface to test the same function, the value of i is always changed by the newly created anonymous thread. This is really confusing me. I understand there's no grantee that the anonymous thread will finish before or after the main thread. But here it seems like Spring test framework did something in background so that the anonymous thread always finished faster than main thread.

Hope someone can explain why this happened or did I misunderstand something. Thank you.

Comment: You should make `private int i = 0;` volatile. Or make `getI()` synchronized.

Comment: I understand there are potential synchronization issue in the code but I'm more interested in why the test results are different. BTW I tried to add volatile and synchronized and the result is stil the same.

Comment: The volatile/synchronized technique is a prerequisite to the assumption that the result of `getI()` reflects the exectuion progress of the thread in the first place.

Comment: I don't think there is any intended fiddling with threads going on in the framework. One guess is that time slicing gets at you when the main thread has to do more work. It may have consumed its time slice already when the new thread becomes runnable and gets interrupted in one case, or finish within its time slice in the other case.

Comment: You have already noted that asynchronous execution is unpredictable. And that's basically all there is to say. Because you cannot know what all the other components in the system are doing at one time (in terms of CPU usage) and what the current state of the decision process of the scheduler is you cannot know when each thread will be scheduled.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyB your explaination makes scense. Prabably main thread consumed more time to run the framework test.

Comment: You could try and experiment by running a `Thread.yield()` or `Thread.sleep(1)` just prior to starting the new thread. This may show that something that happens *before* the relevant code can still influence the scheduling of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out so let me answer my own question.

In the first example (noRest()) it tries to create a new thread (let's call it thread2) which change the value of i. However the main thread in my environment always gets a time slice to read i earlier than thread2. I assume the cpu order is:

1. main thread: creation
2. thread2: creation
3. main thread: reads i
4. thread2: sets i

Hence the result in noRest().

And in the second example rest(), main thread needs to do a little more things like initiating spring boot test framework, so the cpu order is changed. In my specific environment, it always runs like this:

1. main thread: creation
2. thread2: creation
3. main thread: init spring boot test framework
4. thread2: sets i
5. main thread: reads i

Of course the actual cpu slicing is more complicated. But I think it's enough to demonstrate that the order is not garanterad in either of the test cases. The result probably may change if we run it in some other environment. One solution to make both test cases more reliable could be that using Thread.sleep() or Thread.yield() between two threads to make sure that one thread is always finished before the other one.

And thanks for JimmyB's helpful comments.